# How to offload already downloaded photos to iCloud?

Tags: icloud, photos, disk-space

I've setup a new Mac two weeks ago and its already full cause of Photos downloaded from iCloud.

I have the "Photos > Preferences > iCloud > Optimize Mac Storage" checkbox set, but it seems too late now when my disk is already full.

How can I "offload" the photos that has already been downloaded so the library shrinks to a sane size?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it just took some time to take effect, ran the disk util again and free space went back to normal.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. It's all done in the background so you don't have to worry about it.